# почему-то не работают стили для main

Tags: html, css

работают стили для других классов, но для main не работает

```css
.main{
    background-color: brown;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pages/index.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Domstroy</title>
</head>
<body class="body">
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header__logo"><img src="images/home.png" alt="" class="header__logo_img"></div>
        <div class="header__title"></div>
        <div class="header__number"></div>
        <div class="header__mail"></div>
    </header>
<div class="main">       
</div>
     <footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer__number"></div>
        <div class="footer__mail"></div>
    </footer> 
</body>
</html>
```

в DevTools нашел возможную проблему,а именно вместо стиле написано Inherited from body

Comment: Пока что Ваш код не дает никакой информации. В теории всё должно работать. Ищите проблему – незакрытые скобки, опечатки, замена буквы (английской на русскую, например)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Всё отлично работает https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCF5I.png

Comment: Все работает даже в приведенном вами коде. Ищите опечатку.